# Update in MongoDB Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, callback

Is there any scenario that explains why the update is not working, I can't seem to pinpoint the cause and I don't see any errors whatsoever. Is there a way to check the output of the update function because currently the update is not doing anything. That means the last log line shows a value different than 20170615-7702.

```
Db.find().forEach(function(item){
   console.log(item._id+ " =======> " + item.build.parameters.BUILD_NUM);
   Db.update({"_id":item._id}, {$set:{"build.parameters.BUILD_NUM":"20170615-7702"}});
   console.log(Db.findOne({"_id": item._id}).build.parameters.BUILD_NUM);});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above should work. I think that the problem above is that it is not able to update the document as fast as it prints the output. First try:

```
var itemUpdated = Db.findOne({"_id": item._id});
console.log(itemUpdated._id)
```

The other option is very simple go to the command line and run `meteor mongo`. Then see all the entries in the collection and their properties.
Third and maybe the best option to test here is to use `setTimeout()` for the `console.log()`.

Hope it helps.